# Add css li to php?

Tags: php, css, class

When I add a `<li>` element (I want to have all the links in an `<ul>` centered navigation) to this php pagination script, nothing shows up? But works fine when I use span:

```
echo "<span class='activestudent_pagination'>$i</span> &nbsp;";
```

I'm new to PHP and was just wandering if someone could please help me out with what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div id="pages"><ul>
<?php


$show=6;

echo "<li><a href='?i=p&p=$page'>&#171; PREV</a></li>";

if($page-($show/2) > 1){
$temp=$page-$show;
echo "<li><a href='?p=$temp'>...</a></li>";
}

if($page-($show/2) >= 1 && $page+($show/2) <= $pages){
$start=$page-($show/2);
$stop=$page+($show/2);
}

if($page-($show/2) < 1){
$start=1;
$stop=$show;
}
if($page+($show/2) > $pages){
$start=$pages-$show;
$stop=$pages;
}  


for($i=$start; $i<=$stop; $i++){
if($page==$i){
echo "<li class='activespage'>$i</li>";
}
else{
echo "<li><a href='?p=$i'>$i</a></li>";
}
}

if($page+($show/2) < $pages){
$temp=$page+$show;
echo "<li><a href='?p=$temp'>...</a></li>";
}

echo "<li><a href='?i=n&p=$page'>NEXT &#187;</li></a>";

?>
</ul>
```

Comment: what does the generated html source look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to close HTML tags in the reverse order you opened them, so

```
echo "<li><a href='?i=n&p=$page'>NEXT &#187;</li></a>";
```

should be:

```
echo "<li><a href='?i=n&p=$page'>NEXT &#187;</a></li>";
```

That could be the cause of it not displaying right. It's hard to tell without seeing the full HTML output though.

Comment: ...close in the **reverse** order you opened them... :)

Comment: @Jess please post the relevant HTML output or View Source, I don't think anyone can help more without more information. Unless it's actually giving a PHP error message, the PHP code isn't really relevant here.

Comment: I mean, post just the HTML that's generated by the PHP when the page is loaded, and delete any sections (header, footer etc) that aren't relevant to make it easier to see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I'm sorry for the late reply. :( It turned to be a typo in the css, works fine now! :)