# How to add css in php

Tags: php, css

I have a small problem in my code, I just want to change the 'Booking Cart' text to white with php. I changed it several times and it still doesn't work. and I still want to find out how it works I hope you all can help me

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown hidden-caret"> 
<p style="margin-top: 16px; color="#fff">           
<?php 
$text_cart_url = '<i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true" style="color: #fff;"> </i> ';

$text_cart_url .= ' Booking Cart :'. $this->M_perpus->edit_data(array('id_anggota'=>$this->session->userdata('id_agt')),'transaksi')->num_rows() .' Buku ';
?>
<?=anchor('peminjaman/lihat_keranjang', $text_cart_url)?>       
</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add css li to php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817092/add-css-li-to-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can input html code into php variable same as before. example code :

```
$text_cart_url = '<p style="color: #fff;">Booking Cart :</p>' . $this->M_perpus->edit_data(array('id_anggota'=>$this->session->userdata('id_agt')),'transaksi')->num_rows() .' Buku ';;
```